# Element located but not being clicked (nor keys are sent)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Within a Python script to send keys to a field on a URL, I have the following function:

```
def main():
    driver = get_driver()
    time.sleep(2) #Manually increase value when cookies stop working / decrease when they start working again
    driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="//iframe[@id='iframe']").click()
    driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="//iframe[@id='iframe']").send_keys(cuid)
    time.sleep(8)

 #Executing
main()
```

Please ignore the time.sleep as they are just for me to see it working when running the script.

When I run it in PyCharm the URL is opening correctly but the element is not being clicked, however I don't get any error. The process ends with "exit code 0". I just know is not being clicked because when I open the URL manually and click the element myself, its layout turns blue. When inspecting this element I see an alert message under the SelectorHub tab:

> Alert: This element is inside iframe. Switch inside iframe to access it through automation.

I believe the element itself is being found (although not clicked) because I tried couple of different values for the find.element() method and I got that typical error saying that the element could not be located. With the values I posted here, I don't get such error.

Also, the send_keys() method seems not to be working neither, because when I use time.sleep(8) I have time to visualize the element in the browser and nothing gets typed. The keys to be typed are actually an object (cuid) I created before by asking the user to input an int in the Global Scope:

```
cuid = int(input("Enter the CUID you want to reset: "))
```

I have read that the old

```
find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath")
```

has been deprecated, however I cannot find much info about the new one. I'm using:

```
find_element(by="xpath", value="//iframe[@id='iframe']").click()
```

because there is no ID when I inspect the element and some other options for xpath yield the error saying that the element could not be located.

How can I make Selenium click the element and send the keys?

---

Editing to add a snippet of a chunk of html source (when searching for iframe):

```
    <iframe id='iframe' name="frame"
        style="border-width: 0px; overflow: hidden; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;"
        height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
<script src="menuutils/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var blankUrl = "/ops/menuutils/blank.html";

    function getFrameUrl() {
        try {
            var frameUrl = $("#iframe").get(0).contentWindow.location.href;
            var myPreUrl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host;
            if (frameUrl.substring(0, myPreUrl.length) === myPreUrl) {
                frameUrl = frameUrl.substring(myPreUrl.length);
            }
            return frameUrl;
```

Comment: Please share the html page or url which you're testing, so that it's easier to identify the problem. However, whenever, there is any element inside iframe, to access that element , you need to switch to that particular iframe before accessing the element.

Comment: You are clicking or using send keys to an IFRAME. I've never seen a site where the IFRAME itself is interactable. You need to share more info about what element (maybe inside the IFRAME) you are trying to interact with along with the relevant HTML.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies. Unfortunately I cannot share the URL as it belongs to my company. But here is the element I where I want to click and send they keys:

<textarea style="width:100%" rows="4" ng-model="userId" placeholder="CoreUserId" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" xpath="1"></textarea>

Answer (score 1):

Before interacting with any elements inside iframe, you need to switch to iframe. Also, sicne you're using the same element for clicking and sending the keys, you can locate the element once and reuse it. Try below code :

```
def main():
    driver = get_driver()
    time.sleep(2) #Manually increase value when cookies stop working / decrease when they start working again

    iframe_ele = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="//iframe[@id='iframe']")
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_ele)
    iframe_ele.click()
    iframe_ele.send_keys(cuid)
    time.sleep(8)
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
 #Executing
main()
```

Once you're done with accessing and performing send keys, you should switch back to default content using `driver.switch_to.default_content()` as shown in the above code inorder to access other elements which are outside iframe.

Comment: Hi Haris, thank you for your reply.
I tried the suggested code and I get this error message now:
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

The xpath I wrote in that code is the one for the iframe I believe. Is it possible that there is another element inside the iframe where I have to click and send keys?

Comment: @Raul Yes. It is possible that there is another element inside iframe.  Could you please add html source of the web page which you're trying to automate so that it'd be easier to understand.

Comment: Hi @Harish, I cannot share the full source as it is a work web page, but I edited the question to add a snippet of what I see when search for "iframe" on it.

Comment: @Raul Are you trying to sendKeys to the below test area (which you have mentioned in comment above) : ```<textarea style="width:100%" rows="4" ng-model="userId" placeholder="CoreUserId" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" xpath="1"></textarea>``` ?

Comment: If yes, you can make use of this code : ```text_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@ng-model='userId']")
text_area.clear()
text_area.send_keys(cuid)```

Comment: Hi again @Haris, your magic seems to work now. Thank you very much for your time and patience and also for the quick lesson on iframe (which I never encounter before). Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding your first issue(element located but not being clicked):**

1. I hope you are clicking the desired element after switching into the `iframe`? if not, first switch and then try to click on the desired element. Below code is to switch into an `iframe`

```
iframe = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="//iframe[@id='iframe']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

2. Even after switching into an `iframe`, if your code is not able to click on the desired element, then try to perform `click()` using java script, below is the code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath expression of the desired element")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

**Regarding your second issue(`send_keys()` method not working):**

1. If `send_keys()` is not working, try using java script, below is the example code:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('<enter element's ID here>').value='enter value here'")
```

2. Even if it is not workinf with java script, try using Actions Chains, below code for your reference:

```
# create action chain object
action = ActionChains(driver)
  
# click the item
action.click(on_element = element)
  
# send keys
action.send_keys("Enter the value you want to send")
  
# perform the operation
action.perform()
```

**Note:** Do not forget to switch back from `iframe` after all the actions are performed within the `iframe`. Use following code to switch back `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Comment: Thank you Shawn for your reply.

I tried  switching to the iframe as you suggested but the click() action using java script yields the following error:

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

maybe it has been deprecated? in my short experience, to find elements I m using "find_element(by=xxx, value=xxx).

Comment: Also as you pointed out I first need to access the iframe and then click on the desired element within the iframe. I m afraid in the code i pasted in the question I was trying to click on the iframe.

I tried to correct that by using the option "inside iframe" when using SelectorHub and find the xpath. Then I tried this code but it seems to be unable to find the element.

    element = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="//a[position()=25]")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)